# How to backport FreeBSD 13-CURRENT C.UTF-8 locale to 11.2-Release?

Tags: freebsd, locale, backports

I've been [administering a FreeBSD system through SSH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/484832/186590), and she doesn't seem to like the non-ASCII characters I've entered.

One noted in the [bug report](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=233624) that the problem got fixed with the C.UTF-8 locale in 13-CURRENT branch, so I'd like to try to backport that into my current system.

I'd like to ask some experienced user on advice of how to do that smoothly. (Or I'll post a self-answer when I've tried and achieved it myself).

In essence: How do I backport a locale from a different version of FreeBSD?

Comment: I'm wondering if copying the appropriate directory under `/usr/share/locale/` from a FreeBSD 13-CURRENT system is all you need...

Comment: Also, I'll need to make that the default locale for root and some other people. The name of the locale is different: "C.UTF-8" vs "C". So I'm just trying now.

Comment: Yeah, if copying it works, then just update `/etc/login.conf` to make it default... Looks like you're getting there, hopefully you'll find the solution, please post it as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get the 13-CURRENT base.txz on your system, extract it to where convenient.
2. Copy ./usr/share/locale/C.UTF-8 to the root system's /usr/share/locale using `cp -R` command.
3. In `sh` execute `export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8`, and you'll be able to use the C.UTF-8 locale.

Note: Setting locale like this did not cause the SSH to be closed as described in the linked question, so it's probably okey to not touch login.conf at all and use the ".profile" method instead which is more clean.

Comment: Actually, the reverse is the case.  `login.conf` is shell-neutral, and thus cleaner, particularly on an operating system where the C shell is the default for some accounts.  `.profile` is not.