# 'ls name' and 'ls | grep name' with accent different

Tags: grep, freebsd, ls, unicode

I am on Xigmanas (NAS freebsd). I'll explain the situation as simply as possible:

```
:;  set | egrep 'LC_A|LANG'
GDM_LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8
SLIM_LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8

:;  ls -i  1989* ; ls -i | grep 1989 ;  ls -ib  1989* ; ls -ib | grep 1989
9920 1989 Amn??sia.mp4
 9920 1989 Amnésia.mp4
9920 1989 Amn\303\251sia.mp4
 9920 1989 Amn\303\251sia.mp4
```

We see that with `ls` only the accent is transformed into ??
And this is not the case with the pipe followed by `grep`.

I don't see an explanation since the pipe should not modify the byte stream
especially not by correcting the flow!

`ls` followed by `grep` displays correctly while `ls` alone is incorrect.

What's going on?

Comment: What's the output of `locale charmap`? It's possible your system doesn't have a `fr_FR.UTF-8` locale installed or as Chris said that you didn't export that `LC_ALL` variable to the environmnent. Can you see that locale in the output of `locale -a`?

Comment: Other instances where `ls -i 1989*` and `ls -i | grep 1989` would generate different outputs are when there is any file with `1989` in its name but not at the start of the name, or when a file has an inode number that includes the `1989` substring, or (on some systems) if any file whose name starts with `1989` also has one or several embedded newline characters in its name.

Comment: This is tagged `FreeBSD` so I will strongly suggest to use `locale` command to verify and see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/484832/ssh-to-freebsd-in-utf-8/484932#484932) on how to use login classes rather than setting `LC_*` directly. Have you tested with the default `C.UTF8`?

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
ls --show-control-chars A*
Amnésia
```

As does this,

```
ls A* | cat
Amnésia
```

The documentation for the version of `ls` I have on Debian (`ls (GNU coreutils) 8.32`) writes,

> **`--show-control-chars`** show nongraphic characters as-is (the default, unless [...] output is a terminal)

Arguably it's a bug, because the two bytes that represent `é` in a UTF-8 locale (`\303\251`) should be treated as a printing character, not a non-graphic character.

---

And now I cannot reproduce it. Did you `export` your locale variables? I should get a set of results for this command:

```
env | egrep 'LC_A|LANG'
```

If not, try this to `export` the locale variables to the environment:

```
eval $(LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8 locale | sed 's/^/export /' )
```

Then retry:

```
ls A*
Amnésia
```

Comment: What do you suppose it means for the `ls` man page to say, “unless program is 'ls'”?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' I don't know. I wonder if it implies that `ll` and any other variations on the theme are implemented by `ls` itself

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' and Chris I thought that option might show up in [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html) for other GNU coreutils tools too and I found `--show-control-chars` mentioned as also being an option for `pr` (possibly not relevant to this). Under [Directory Listing](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Directory-listing.html), though, the command `dir` is discussed as equivalent to `ls -C -b`, and `vdir` as equivalent to `ls -l -b`, both heavily referencing the mentioned `ls` documentation which I expect is relevant.

Comment: @EdMorton ah! Thankyou

Comment: I've removed the confusing subclause from the quote, EdMorton, G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica'

Comment: can't reproduce either, I always get accent right.

Comment: Hello,I am on  Xigmanas (NAS freebsd)

:; set | egrep 'PS1|LC_ALL|LANG'
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
PS1=':; '
:; éùà
-bash: éùà: command not found

:; touch "1989 Amnésia.mp4"
:; ls -a 1989*
1989 Amnésia.mp4

:; LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
:; set | egrep 'LANG'
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8

:; ls -a 1989*
1989 Amn??sia.mp4
:;

:; LANG=en_US.UTF-8
:; ls -a 1989*
1989 Amnésia.mp4

Comment: are you on a mounted ressources ?  (e.g. either samba or NFS), if so, can you edit your post with mount options ? (`/etc/fstab` or command line or revelent line from `mount`)

Comment: Be aware that `--show-control-chars` is a GNU ls option. You should probably be using `-B` - see [ls(1)](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ls&sektion=1). Or [install GNU ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/760199/how-to-sort-and-filter-images-by-modification-time-and-view-them-in-nsxiv-on-fre/760241#760241).
For FreeBSD it is furthermore recommended to [use login classes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/484832/ssh-to-freebsd-in-utf-8/484932#484932) rather than setting `LC_*` directly.

Comment: @ClausAndersen my original answer (this one here) responded to the question when it didn't have the [tag:freebsd] tag. I added that in response to a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/771964/ls-name-and-ls-grep-name-with-accent-different/771974?noredirect=1#comment1474020_771974) made after my most recent answer edit. You'd be welcome to write your own answer that makes use of the newest information

Comment: Nah - you got the most important bit "Arguably it's a bug,". Most likely `locale` is not set correctly. Xigmanas is unknown to me.